# How to perform database table rename while reading from it

Tags: mysql, innodb

After consulting the MySQL manual [1,2], it seems like performing a rename of a table needs a global table lock. Some quick experiments confirm this. This means that if any `SELECT` statements are executing against this table, the `RENAME` operation will block until the `SELECT` statements finish executing.

I was wondering whether it is possible with InnoDB or any other database engine (PostgreSQL maybe?) where read-only operations do not block the database from performing a `RENAME table`.

I would imagine that the `SELECT` continues to read from the new table name if the two operations happen concurrently.

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html

[2] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Why would you want to rename a live table being currently used at that moment anyway?

Comment: That is a long and complicated answer :-)

Comment: NO, that's absurd and shouldn't be done. It's like you sent a post to an address and while the post in middle way someone changed the city name; what would the state of the post you sent?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 introduces online DDL, but it seems table renaming is not among them. But table renaming is quick, so unless you have big SELECTs which are running for hours, you should not have an issue. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html

Comment: That's not entirely true. And I would really prefer not to go into the details of why we're trying to do this. Think of it like this though: a table can be used to represent a snapshot of data in time. If I initiate a read against that table right now, I'm interested in the data at this moment in time. If the data moves on, I don't care, let me finish my read query against the table I started reading from (even though it has a new name, it's probably just a pointer anyway).

Comment: @Marki555 Thanks Marki for the input. I realise that renaming is pretty quick. In our case though, the rename happens every 60 seconds. Even though our SELECTs should, in theory, be quick (less than a few seconds), I'd prefer to avoid this potential issue altogether. Of course, if there is no other alternative, we'll just add a timeout on all SELECT statements.

Comment: Can't you just name the table correctly upon creation? So instead of creating new `tbl` and then renaming to `tbl_20150714xy`, create with the latter name and decide which table to query at the SELECT time.

Comment: That will work. Something along the lines of having always two tables, one active and one passive, and putting the complexity on the user to select the right table... But it's a bit of an ugly solution to the problem. I had hoped some database engine has a setting that allows selects to "follow" the table.

Comment: *In our case though, the rename happens every 60 seconds*. Then you have an application design problem. Rather than renaming tables, have a mapping within the app (or in a table) so the app queries the correct table. Rotate the mapping rather than renaming the tables.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that a mapping will indeed work (as my comment above suggested). I won't really call it an application design problem, though. Creating a mapping (in the app or in the table) just shifts complexity from one place to another. In my opinion this is something that a database engine could solve, but because the feature is not available, the complexity has to live somewhere else. By introducing a mapping, the onus is on the application querying the database to be intelligent about which table it is querying.

Comment: I tagged it with PostgreSQL, hoping that some experts on the database could allude as to whether it is possible. Unfortunately, I'm mostly familiar with MySQL. We've also considered other solutions, such as a load balancer across the read-only fleet that will free up one database at a time to complete the table renames.